# Пустые процессы Linux

Tags: linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скажите что это за пустые процессы и почему они появляются в системе? Запущенные от root и не занимающие ресурсы.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Внёс.

Comment: Они не пустые. Просто у Вас настроено не полное отображение информации о них. Нажмите F2 и добавьте столбиков.

Comment: Это демоны системные важные системные дела делающие.

Comment: Это нитки ядра. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266434/are-kernel-threads-processes-and-daemons